# passing operators to pandas dataframe in function:

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I want to iterate say I have pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
tmp = pd.DataFrame([(2,2),(0,4),(1,3)],columns= ['A','B'])
```

and I want to write something of the following kind:

```
def f(operator,column)
```

s.t

```
f('mean','A')
```

will return:

```
tmp['A'].mean()
```

Comment: why close vote? question is detailed enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, use `getattr`:

```py
tmp = pd.DataFrame([(2,2),(0,4),(1,3)], columns=['A','B'])

def f(operator, column):
    return getattr(tmp[column], operator)()

f('mean', 'A')
# 1.0

f('max', 'B')
# 4
```

Answer (score 2):

As the complement of @mozway answer, you can use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
>>> tmp.agg({'A': 'mean', 'B': 'max'})
A    1.0
B    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Take a look at the last lines of code of `agg` [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/3b163de02f666a2342e18468cba7d6c286f526bf/pandas/core/apply.py#L150-L176): it already uses `getattr`.